# Tensorflow PS device selection issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed

I'm studying on tensorflow, 
and I'm thinking about some algorithm to select adaptable device for PS 
by efficiency of each worker and network bandwidth etc..

and today, I found a performance guide on the tensorflow homepage below
https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide 
so in this page, they said that "Place shared Parameters on GPU" is increasing performance.

but, I don't know, why the performance is increased.

so here are my questions.
What do you think of device selection idea for the PS in the distributed tensorflow? 
If many devices is needed in the heterogeneous machine learning environment, I think it will be good, what do you think?

and "Place shared Parameters on GPU" what is this meaning?